# R Shiny tabsetPanel displaying strange tab name?

Tags: r, shiny

I am working with shinydashboard and using `tabsetPanel`, however strange name/number appears on the each `tabPanel` in the upper-left corner (like: **tab-4750-1** and the number changes). 
Does anyone know how i can remove it?

Hint: The problem appears in the `menuItem`: Tabelle & Plots

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Tabelle & Plots", icon = icon("area-chart"), tabName = "tabelle")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard"

      ),

      tabItem(tabName = "tabelle",
              tabsetPanel(id="tabs",width = NULL, height = "800px",  selected = 1,
                          tabPanel(value=1,title="Tabelle filtern", 
                                   fluidRow(
                                     column(12,
                                            box(width = NULL, div(style = 'overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll;max-height: 650px; position:relative;', 
                                                                  dataTableOutput("tabelle")))))),
                          tabPanel("Plots", value = 2,
                                   fluidRow(
                                     column(12, 
                                            box(width = NULL, plotOutput("plot", height=650)),
                                            box(status = "danger",width = NULL,div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll;position:relative;', 
                                                                                   dataTableOutput("tabelle2")))))))

      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks for help!

Cheers

Comment: Problem with `width = NULL,` into  `tabsetPanel(`. For what you need it here? `tabsetPanel` hasnt parametrs `width` and `height`

Comment: Hey, that was the problem! Thanks for the solution! Well while working with shiny i used few times width=NULL (as i had the problems with width of the boxes) and it just came to me automatically (recently discovered the tabsetPanel). Thanks!